# Deployment issue in GlassFish 2.1.1

Tags: java, glassfish, glassfish-2.x

I just created a new domain in GF 2.1.1 and was trying to deploy a WAR but getting below error during deployment:

> Trying to create reference for application in target server failed;
>   Bad File parameter in AppDD ctor: E:\softwares extracted\glassfish
>   2\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\j2ee-apps\MEjbApp Bad File
>   parameter in AppDD ctor: E:\softwares extracted\glassfish
>   2\glassfish\domains\domain1\applications\j2ee-apps\MEjbApp

Please help if I am missing anything in server configuration or somewhere else.